# Why is my class not being picked up via reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to create a unit test to verify that my method to load AutoMapper configurations works correctly.  My idea to load AutoMapper configurations is to put the configuration calls in classes with the following interface:

```
public interface IEntityMapConfiguration
{
    void ConfigureMapping();
}
```

To load these dynamically, I have the following loader class

```
public class EntityMapLoader
{
    public static void LoadEntityMappings()
    {
        // Load all IEntityMapConfiguration classes via reflection
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                             .GetAssemblies()
                             .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                             .Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration)))
                             .Select(x => x as IEntityMapConfiguration)
                             .ToList();

        foreach (var config in types)
            config.ConfigureMapping();
    }
}
```

To verify this I have created the following unit test

```
public class UnitTestEntityViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Text2 { get; set; }
}

public class TestProjectionMapping : IEntityMapConfiguration
{
    public void ConfigureMapping()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<UnitTestEntity, UnitTestEntityViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Text2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Text));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class AutomapperConfigurationTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Loader_Loads_All_Configurations_In_Assembly()
    {
        // Setup
        UnitTestEntity entity = new UnitTestEntity { Id = 2, Text = "Test 1234" };

        // Act
        EntityMapLoader.LoadEntityMappings();

        // Verify
        UnitTestEntityViewModel result = Mapper.Map<UnitTestEntity, UnitTestEntityViewModel>(entity);
        Assert.AreEqual(entity.Id, result.Id, "View model's ID value did not match");
        Assert.AreEqual(entity.Text, result.Text2, "View model's text value did not match");
    }
}
```

The problem is that this unit test fails because it's not picking up my `TestProjectionMapping` class, and I can't figure out why.  In my `LoadEntityMappings()` the `types` list has a count of zero.  I have verified that my test assembly is returned from `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.

I'm sure I am doing something obviously wrong, but I can't find it.  Any ideas?

---

**Edit**: I updated my `LoadentityMappings()` method to be:

```
    public static void LoadEntityMappings()
    {
        // Load all IEntityMapConfiguration classes via reflection
        var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                             .GetAssemblies()
                             .SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())
                             .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration)))
                             .Select(x => x as IEntityMapConfiguration)
                             .ToList();

        foreach (var config in types)
            config.ConfigureMapping();
    }
```

This is still failing.  The statement (without the final select) is returning my `TestProjectionMapping` class, but the `x as IEntityMapconfiguration` is failing.  In the debugger when I type `(IEntityMapConfiguration)types[0]` I get the following error:

`Cannot cast 'types[0]' (which has an actual type of 'System.RuntimeType') to 'MyJobLeads.DomainModel.EntityMapping.IEntityMapConfiguration'`

For reference in the watch list typing `types[0]` shows:

`types[0]   {Name = "TestProjectionMapping" FullName = "MyJobLeads.Tests.TestProjectionMapping"}    System.Type {System.RuntimeType}`

Also, `types[0] is IEntityMapConfiguration` is `false`

I'm not sure why I can't do this cast, any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) to see if a type implements an interface. You have to use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) (or you can use `is IEntityMapConfiguration` or `Type.GetInterfaces` and then see if the resulting sequence contains `typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration)`.

Now think about why you can't use `Type.IsSubclassOf` to see if a `Type` implements an interface. Because we don't say that a class that implements an interface is a subclass of that interface; instead we say that it *implements* the interface, and we reserve *is subclass of* for its base class (`object` or `ValueType` unless one is specified).

By the way, this is **clearly** spelled out in the documentation for `Type.IsSubclassOf`:

> The `IsSubclassOf` method cannot be used to determine whether an interface derives from another interface, or whether a class implements an interface.

Comment: Oh duh.  However, I changd it to `IsAssignableFrom` but the `.Select(x => x as IEntityMapConfiguration)` is returning null instead of the type.

Comment: Make sure that you have `Where(x => typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(x))`. It's likely that you have it reversed. You want to know if instsances of type `IEntityMapConfiguration` can be assigned from instances of type `x`, where `x` is the parameter in your lambda expression (it's a common mistake to reverse this test).

Comment: Also using `is IEntityMapconfiguration` returns zero results, and I tried reversing the `IsAssignablefrom(x)` by doing `.Where(x => typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(x))` and all results were null after the last select

Comment: Okay, you obviously need to start doing some debugging. Start by checking the list of assemblies `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`. Does it contain the one you expect it to? Then check the types (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(x => x.GetTypes())`? Does it contain the type that you expect it to? Then check if `typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(X))` returns true. What about `typeof(X) is IEntityMapConfiguration`? What about `typeof(X).GetInterfaces.Contains(typeof(IEntityMapConfiguration))`?

Comment: I updated with those debugging efforts.  I'm not really sure why the casts and `is` isn't working for this.

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I'm being stupid and need to instantiate the type, I can't just cast it.  Today is not my day

Answer (score 3):

Use IsAssignableFrom()

From MSDN:

> The IsSubclassOf method cannot be used to determine whether an interface derives from another   interface, or whether a class implements an interface.